# How to set NavigationView.SelectedItem programmatically by tag

Tags: c#, uwp

In my XAML I have

```
...
    <NavigationView Name="NavView"
                    PaneDisplayMode="LeftCompact"
                    Loaded="NavView_Loaded">
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            ...
            <NavigationViewItem Tag="movies" Icon="Folder" Content="Movies" />
            ...
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
    </NavigationView>
...
```

In the codebehind I would like to set the selected menu item using the tag property of the NavigationMenuItem. I know I can do something like

```
NavView.SelectedItem = NavView.MenuItems[3];
```

but I want to be able to do this, like I said, using the tag property instead of an index value. This is because if I change the menu item order, I don't want to have to go back and change the index value in the codebehind.

Thank you in advance for any help given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply code something like this...

```
for (var i=0; i < NavView.MenuItems.Length; i++)
     if (NavView.MenuItems[i].Tag == YOUR_TAG)
         NavView.SelectedItem = NavView.MenuItems[i];
```

Linq version

```
NavView.SelectedItem = NavView.MenuItems.Where(x => (Framework​Element)x.Tag == YOUR_TAG);
```

Comment: I was trying to do something with Linq. I am very new to UWP, and windows app development in general.  Thank you.

Comment: @master_ruko I added the LINQ version of it... in case you want to write it in one line.

Comment: I tried the Linq way but I get an error saying 'object' does not contain a definition for Tag

Comment: This is what I had to use: ((FrameworkElement)x).Tag.ToString()
Thank you for getting me to a place where I could figure out the rest!

Comment: It also worked if I changed FrameworkElement to NavigationViewItem

Comment: @master_ruko yep that's because the FrameworkELement is the Base class of NaviagtionViewItem.